# Greek characters, Regular Expressions, and C#

Tags: c#, regex, unicode, utf-8, internationalization

I'm building a CMS for a scientific journal and that uses a lot of Greek characters.  I need to validate a field to include a specific character set and Greek characters.  Here's what I have now:

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9-()/\s]
```

How do I get this to include Greek characters in addition to alphanumeric, '(', ')', '-', and '_'?

I'm using C#, by the way.

Comment: Which programming language?

Comment: Why does language matter? RegEx has standards of its own, hasn't it?

Comment: Programming language *and* string format (locale) are both important.

Comment: Different languages support different regexp syntax and char classes.

Comment: @Romain Muller: There are many different regular expression implementations (see http://www.regular-expressions.info/refflavors.html). They all share the same basics but also support different features. Knowledge of these features can help in this case.

Comment: @Gumbo: Right. I figured there would be a way to propose a generic enough solution with pointers to implementation specifics...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In .NET languages, you can use `\p{IsGreekandCoptic}` to match Greek characters. So the resulting regex is

```
[^a-zA-Z0-9-()/\s\p{IsGreekandCoptic}]
```

`\p{IsGreekandCoptic}` matches:

[These characters will be matched by \p{IsGreekandCoptic} http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/3760/greekcoptic.png](http://img203.imageshack.us/img203/3760/greekcoptic.png)

Comment: which tool did you use to make the "characters in this block" image?

Comment: Hi, this pattern doesn't work for me, what am i missing?
^[A-Za-z0-9\p{IsGreekandCoptic} \-\.]+$

Comment: @Efthimis: Which language are you using this regex in? And what exactly do you mean by "doesn't work"?

Comment: @Tim Pietzcker Im using asp.net mvc framework, wherever i write Greek letters in my input i get my validations error message

Comment: And how exactly are you using the regex? Did you escape it correctly or use a verbatim string?

Comment: Yep i did, here's my sample
[RegularExpression(@"^[A-Za-z0-9\p{IsGreekandCoptic} \-\.]+$",..)]

Answer (score 5):

If you're using a language that uses PCRE for regular expressions and UTF-8, `/[\x{0374}-\x{03FF}]+/u` should match Greek characters. Greek characters fall between U+0374 and U+03FF ([source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Unicode_characters#Greek_and_Coptic)), and the `u` modifier tells PCRE to use unicode. As commented below, `/\p{Greek}+/u` works as well with PCRE.

If you're using Javascript, it uses `\uXXXX` instead of `\x{XXXX}`: `/[\u0374-\u03FF]+/`.

Also see this guide to [Unicode Regular Expressions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html) for more information.

Comment: If you have PCRE, just use `\p{Greek}`.

Answer (score 1):

For Java, from the Pattern javadoc:

> \p{InGreek}   A character in the Greek
>   block (simple block)

Answer (score 1):

Being my first response on SO, I can't downvote Daniel's answer on javascript regex.

I know this is very late, but Daniel's answer is incorrect. It excludes the ancient characters below! This is important if you're working on a Bible app that researches words in ancient Greek!

This is the correct regex for finding greek & coptic in js:

```
/[\u0370-\u03FF]+/gm
```

http://unicode.org/charts/PDF/U0370.pdf

Excerpt from chart:

> 0370 Ͱ GREEK CAPITAL LETTER HETA
>       → 2C75 Ⱶ  latin capital letter half h
>
> 0371 ͱ GREEK SMALL LETTER HETA
>       → 2C76 ⱶ  latin small letter half h
>
> 0372 Ͳ GREEK CAPITAL LETTER ARCHAIC SAMPI
>
> 0373 ͳ GREEK SMALL LETTER ARCHAIC SAMPI

EDIT: Craig points out that Daniel's regex is correct for the OP. While I can't find where the OP specifies which Greek text he's evaluating, I'll concede that my response is only valid for ancient texts.

While I'm editing this, I want to also point out that no regex here matches Greek characters with the kind of accenting that Perseus adds to their texts. So if you happen to install the http://www.perseus.tufts.edu/hopper/, or use any of their public domain resources in an app, be careful with my regex.

Comment: Thank you for the contribution and welcome to SO. The question was asked in the context of modern state of the Greek alphabet and not the ancient version of the alphabet.